# If $0\le \phi\le 1$ then prove that $\int_0^1\phi(s)ds<1. $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, riemann-integration

Assume that $\phi:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ is a continuous map which is not identically equal to 1.
 Then prove that:

$$\int_0^1 \phi(s)ds<1.$$
My attempt. $0\le \phi\le 1$ I directly get

$$\int_0^1 \phi(s)ds \le 1.$$
But the inequality is large rather than strict inequality. How can I prove it with the strict ineqaulaity?

Comment: There is a $t$ with $\phi(t) < 1$. Then by continuity …

Comment: use darboux upper sum using that if $\phi$ isn't identity of 1 then there is an interval in which the area under the function is less then the length of the interval multiplied by 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a point $x_0$ where $f(x_0) \neq 1$.  Since $f$ is continuous, there is a small enough neighborhood of $x_0$, $[x_0 - \frac{\delta}{2}, x_0 +\frac{\delta}{2}]$ where $f \neq 1$ on that neighborhood. This $f$ has a max, $C <1$, on that  interval since it's compact.  Thus $$\int_{0}^{1} \phi(s) ds  \leq (1-\delta) + C\delta < 1$$

Answer (score 4):

$$1-\int_0^1 \phi(s) ds = \int_0^1 (1-\phi(s))ds$$

Since $1-\phi \geq 0$, $\int_0^1 (1-\phi(s))ds\geq 0$ and if the integral is $0$, then $1-\phi = 0$ (which contradicts your assumption on $\phi$).

The last fact follows from a standard lemma for continuous functions over a closed interval.

Answer (score 1):

Assume the equality hold, then 
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1}(1-\phi(x))=0.
\end{align*}
As $1-\phi\geq 0$ is also continuous, then $1-\phi(x)=0$ for all $x\in[0,1]$. This can be argued by some heavier machinery that at least it must be true that $1-\phi=0$ a.e., but continuity can remove the a.e. condition.

Comment: I wrote earlier, but I can't prove to you.

Comment: @GuyFsone Happens often in mathematics that people think of the same proof. No need to accuse people of copying.

Comment: And I believe there is a subtle difference, at least I used a.e. condition to conclude the proof (although there is a simpler one), am I writing the same lines with the first answer?

Answer (score 0):

If $\varphi$ is not identically equal to $1$ then here is a $x_0\in [0,1]$ and $\epsilon>0$ such that $1-\varphi(x_0)>\epsilon$. By the continuity of $\varphi$ there exists an interval $[x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta]$ such that it is worth the inequality 
$$
1-\varphi(x)>0,\quad \forall x\in [x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta].
$$
Supposing absurd that we have equality
$
\int_{0}^{1}\varphi(x)\mathrm{\, d \,} x=1 .
$ 
Note that $\int_{0}^{1} 1 \mathrm{\,d\,}x=1$ implies 
$$
\int_{0}^{1}\underbrace{(1-\varphi(x))}_{\geq 0} \rm d x =0
$$
But
$$
\int_{0}^{1}\underbrace{(1-\varphi(x))}_{\geq 0} \rm d x
\geq
\int_{x_0-\delta}^{x_0+\delta}\underbrace{(1-\varphi(x))}_{\geq \epsilon} \rm d x
\geq 
\int_{x_0-\delta}^{x_0+\delta}{ \epsilon}\;\; \rm d x
=
\epsilon \cdot 2\cdot \delta >0
$$
So we can only conclude that
$$
\int_{0}^{1}\varphi(x) \,{\rm d } x<1.
$$